# Just a quick question about this inequality

Tags: inequality

I have a proof in my text book which I understand, but theres just one step that I'm not sure is correct.

it says:

$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{3}< \frac{1}{\varepsilon }$$
is equal to
 $$2^{n-1}> \frac{3}{\varepsilon }$$

I'm just a bit confused because it seems like all theyve done is multiply both sides of the first inequality by 3, so I don't understand why they flipped the inequality sign in the second. Is this a typo in the textbook or I missing something really obvious.

Comment: This appears to be a typo.

Comment: ok. Thanks guys!

Comment: Shouldn't we bring this out of the unanswered tab?